# Need help to simplify this T-SQL query

Tags: sql, mssql-jdbc

I have this working T-SQL query, is there any way to simplify it?

The `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tablename` is repeating and only the condition is different for each query, so is there a way to simplify this more? thank you

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table 
WHERE columnA = 'I' AND columnB = 'I' AND columnC =''

UNION ALL

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table 
WHERE columnA = 'I' AND columnB = 'I' AND columnC <>''

UNION ALL

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table
WHERE columnA IN ('A','R') AND columnB = 'I' AND columnD IN (SELECT columnE FROM Table2)

UNION ALL

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table 
WHERE columnA IN ('B') AND columnB = 'I'

UNION ALL

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table 
WHERE columnA IN ('R') AND columnB = 'S'

UNION ALL

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table 
WHERE columnA IN ('A') AND columnB = 'S'
```

This is the working query and my output is 6 rows, want to maintain that

Answer (score 0):

Let me assume that `BI_BRH` is unique in `STDHOST`.  This is not strictly necessary but it are simplifying.

Then you can use conditional aggregation.  I think putting the values in columns is the simplest approach:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'I' AND TRX_STATE = 'I' AND ASSIGN_TO = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
       SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'I' AND TRX_STATE = 'I' AND ASSIGN_TO <>'' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
       SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS IN ('A','R') AND TRX_STATE = 'I' AND s.BI_BRH IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
       SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS IN ('B') AND TRX_STATE = 'I' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
       SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS IN ('R') AND TRX_STATE = 'S' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
       SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS IN ('A') AND TRX_STATE = 'S' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM ICSCHQINFO i LEFT JOIN
     STDHOST s
     ON s.BI_BRH = i.BRH_ASSIGN_TO;
```

Comment: is there a way for it to be written in this format -> SELECT SUM........
FROM (SELECT........FROM......WHERE.....GROUP BY.........UNION ALL SELECT.......FROM........WHERE......GROUP BY.......)a
GROUP BY........

Comment: @KelveenRaj . . . Perhaps.  But there are simpler ways to unpivot if you want separate rows.  And an explicit `GROUP BY` is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Your code runs 6 times over the same table, with different conditions in the `WHERE` clause and returns 6 rows.

Assuming that the 6 conditions you have are mutually exclusive, you can create a CTE that returns for each row the *category* that it belongs to and then aggregate on that category:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT CASE 
           WHEN STATUS = 'I' AND TRX_STATE = 'I' AND ASSIGN_TO = '' THEN 'cat1'
           WHEN STATUS = 'I' AND TRX_STATE = 'I' AND ASSIGN_TO <> '' THEN 'cat2'
           WHEN STATUS IN ('A','R') AND TRX_STATE = 'I' AND BRH_ASSIGN_TO IN (SELECT BI_BRH FROM STDHOST) THEN 'cat3'
           WHEN STATUS IN ('B') AND TRX_STATE = 'I' THEN 'cat4'
           WHEN STATUS IN ('R') AND TRX_STATE = 'S' THEN 'cat5'
           WHEN STATUS IN ('A') AND TRX_STATE = 'S' THEN 'cat6'
         END category
  FROM ICSCHQINFO          
)
SELECT category, COUNT(*) counter
FROM cte
GROUP BY category
```

If there are no rows for any of the categories and in that case you want a row with `0`, you need another CTE that returns the categories and `LEFT` join to the other CTE:

```
WITH 
  categories AS (SELECT category FROM (VALUES ('cat1'), ('cat2'), ('cat3'), ('cat4'), ('cat5'), ('cat6')) v(category)),
  cte AS (
    SELECT CASE 
             WHEN STATUS = 'I' AND TRX_STATE = 'I' AND ASSIGN_TO = '' THEN 'cat1'
             WHEN STATUS = 'I' AND TRX_STATE = 'I' AND ASSIGN_TO <> '' THEN 'cat2'
             WHEN STATUS IN ('A','R') AND TRX_STATE = 'I' AND BRH_ASSIGN_TO IN (SELECT BI_BRH FROM STDHOST) THEN 'cat3'
             WHEN STATUS IN ('B') AND TRX_STATE = 'I' THEN 'cat4'
             WHEN STATUS IN ('R') AND TRX_STATE = 'S' THEN 'cat5'
             WHEN STATUS IN ('A') AND TRX_STATE = 'S' THEN 'cat6'
           END category
    FROM ICSCHQINFO          
  )
SELECT c.category, COUNT(t.category) counter
FROM categories c LEFT JOIN cte t
ON t.category = c.category
GROUP BY c.category
```

Comment: Is there a way for it to be written in this format ->                                                                             SELECT SUM........
FROM (SELECT........FROM......WHERE.....GROUP BY.........UNION ALL SELECT.......FROM........WHERE......GROUP BY.......)a
GROUP BY........

Comment: @KelveenRaj Why? You already have the code with UNION ALL. Don't you want to simplify it?